# Woocommerce "Add to cart" text is "product price" or, if price is 0, "custom text"

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm noob in coding. But there is a problem that I can not solve without help. I also did not find any solutions on the Internet or found only parts of the solution but I do not know how to combine them. 
Example:
ADD TO CART ---> $9.99
or (if prise is zero)
ADD TO CART ---> FREE

What i have. Both working, but i don't know how to combine this...

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'my_custom_cart_button_text', 10 );

function my_custom_cart_button_text() {
global $product;
    if (@$product->product_type == 'simple') {
        return __(get_woocommerce_currency_symbol().@$product->price, 'woocommerce');
    } else {
        // If needed the default behavior for all other products:
        // return __('My default text', 'woocommerce');
    }
}
```

and

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'price_zero' );

function price_zero() {
    global $product;
    if( $product->get_price() == 0 )
    return __( 'Free', 'woocommerce' );
}
```

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just roll the above into one filter!

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'my_custom_cart_button_text', 10 );

function my_custom_cart_button_text() {
    global $product;
    $default = get_woocommerce_currency_symbol().$product->price;
    $free = __('Free',  'woocommerce');
    $button_txt = ($product->get_price() == 0)?$free:$default;
    return __('Add to cart', 'woocommerce').' --&gt; '.$button_txt;
}
```

Or modify your `my_custom_cart_button_text($default)` adding the `$default` argument to get the changes made via the `price_zero` function and make sure it has a number lower than 10 for its priority.

Comment: @Adam Montana glad it helped ;)

Comment: @Dhaval Shah Sorry. I am here first time. Your answer is accepted. ;)

Comment: Not my answer Adam.